# Firebase Cloud Massaging - Push Notifications Server Keys Handle

Tags: server, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I want to add push notification to my app with Firebase Cloud Messaging but I don't know the right way to set this up.

My App Logic is: I have multiple customers (companies) who host their own server's own database and their own users. Some of the employees of the different customers will download the app to receive push notifications from their company's server which implements the firebase admin SDK to send push notifications.

How is it possible to handle all customers from one FCB or is it even possible?

So the customer can just enter the created „server key/topic or project id / UUID“ to his server configuration and can receive the push notification.
They should also not be allowed to see any data from other customers or send messages to them.
At the end of the day, I need to handle all customer

Answer (score 0):

Using the Admin SDK allows one to **send** messages, it does not allow you to **receive** messages. So from that perspective it sounds like the approach suits your needs.

The customers using the Admin SDK will also get full administrative access to your entire Firebase project though. So if you use any other Firebase products aside from Cloud Messaging, that would be a security risk.

Comment: So i could connect all the Server`s from my Customers to my FCB. And just with the DeviceTokens handle the Information Traffic right?  Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "FCB" here?

Comment: I mean FCM sorry.

Comment: In that case my answer is all I can say about it. I explain both what *is* possible, and some considerations to keep in mind.